# Socket connection to smtp server timesout

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have written a simple code to connect to smtp server in java and deployed to amazon.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SocketClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Socket s = new Socket();
                try {
                        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com",25));

                } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println("Connected");
        }
}
```

On local system it works reliably. But if run it continiously on Amazon Ec2 micro instance with ubuntu server, it fails after 3 times. Then I need to wait for couple of minutes and then retry. The line failing is s.connect. It never returns and throws a java connect error. Unable to reproduce the same on Local windows system. Is there something i am missing. The security policy is fine because it works first three times.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but Amazon EC2 may be blocking large numbers of SMTP connections to prevent spam abuse, and you may be hitting a low ratelimit of some sort. If trying to send authenticated mail OUT through Google, use the alternate ports Google provides for SMTP.

Comment: to add to what @hexafraction said: you might think about using a connection pool too, this will keep connections instead of reopening them often.

Comment: I have read through amazon guidelines, they rate limit the out going smtp traffic and one needs to fill the following form to https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true

Comment: @Marge: I have written this as a sample code to illustrate the problem. Original code has a pool. Thanks